# C# - YAXLib: "No elements with this name found:"

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, yaxlib

I have two classes that are used for de/serializing an XML file.

**XmlExampleBasicUnit.cs**:

```
[YAXSerializeAs("Unit")]
public class XmlExampleBasicUnit
{
    [YAXSerializeAs("StringVar")]
    public String StringVar { get; set; }
    [YAXSerializeAs("Int32Var")]
    public Int32 Int32Var { get; set; }
    [YAXSerializeAs("DoubleVar")]
    public Double DoubleVar { get; set; }
    [YAXSerializeAs("DateTimeVar")]
    public String DateTimeVar { get; set; }
    [YAXSerializeAs("CharVar")]
    public String CharVar { get; set; }
}
```

**XmlExampleCollectionOfUnits.cs**:

```
[YAXSerializeAs("CollectionOfUnits")]
public class XmlExampleCollectionOfUnits
{
    [YAXSerializeAs("Units")]
    public List<XmlExampleBasicUnit> Units { get; set; }

    public XmlExampleCollectionOfUnits(List<XmlExampleBasicUnit> units)
    {
        Units = units;
    }

    public XmlExampleCollectionOfUnits()
    {
    }
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CollectionOfUnits>
<Units>
    <Unit>
        <StringVar>TohleJeString</StringVar>
        <Int32Var>24</Int32Var>
        <DoubleVar>29.6</DoubleVar>
        <DateTimeVar>17.11.1968</DateTimeVar>
        <CharVar>c</CharVar>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
        <StringVar>TohleJeTakéString</StringVar>
        <Int32Var>17</Int32Var>
        <DoubleVar>5.9</DoubleVar>
        <DateTimeVar>06.07.1415</DateTimeVar>
        <CharVar>p</CharVar>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
        <StringVar>NoATohleTaké</StringVar>
        <Int32Var>2</Int32Var>
        <DoubleVar>78.5</DoubleVar>
        <DateTimeVar>06.12.1774</DateTimeVar>
        <CharVar>x</CharVar>
    </Unit>
</Units>
```

It's all handled by this function:

```
public T Import<T>(String fileName) where T : class
{
    YAXSerializer serializer = new YAXSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(fileName);
}
```

When I run the code I get following error: `No elements with this name found: './Units'.` As you can see there already is an element called `Units`.

Comment: it doesn't give me any error ! how did you call  `Import` function?

Comment: Thank you! I have realized the `Import()` function is reading incorrect values.

Comment: you need to pass xml content to `Import` function rather than passing path of xml file

Comment: What if I want to use path of XML file?

Comment: then you have to fetch content of xml in your `Import` function from path. let me add an solution for you

Comment: how did u received this xml, means => from physical file or from api or any else?

Comment: It was generated by `XmlTextWriter`.

Comment: could you please add the code that you call `Import` function and xml generation from `XmlTextWriter`?

Comment: Here it is: https://paste.mod.gg/adanapular.cpp
As you can see I would like to implement the `path` variable into a `Import` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184404/discussion-between-chyu-and-er-shoaib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read all your xml content from your path by using `File.ReadAllText(fileName)` and pass it to `Deserialize` method like.

```
public static T Import<T>(String fileName) where T : class
{
    string xmlData = File.ReadAllText(fileName);              //Read xml content from path
    YAXSerializer serializer = new YAXSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlData);                //Pass xml content to Deserialize.
}
```